# Ajax call on checkoutpage regarding address and shippingcosts not executed anymore

Tags: magento-2.1, onepage-checkout, ajax

Magento ver. 2.1.6

Suddenly the one page checkout is not working anymore, the user can not go to the next step after she/he entered a valid address.

I can see in chrome developer network tab that the ajax call, which checks if the email exists in the system, is executed.

But after then, nothing happens anymore. I type in the address, but no ajax call is executed to transfer the address and calculate the shipping costs and so no "proceed checkout" button is shown.

I MUST refresh the browser (ie. press F5) in order to be able to continue.

I know, i did a "Flush Magento Cache" two days ago, but i can not believe that this caused this weird behavior.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

don't know is there an ajax call, i think not...

it was a configuration error, this helped me:

The default Tax Destination country (under Sales -> Tax) was set to USA while that was not one of the allowed countries under General -> General

related to:
[Magento 2: Checkout button missing](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/119825/magento-2-checkout-button-missing)